# Can anyone explain this 2 lines of python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is code submitted by someone in [codeforce](https://codeforces.com/problemset/submission/1030/43337134).

input :

```
3       //no of elements in next line
0 0 1   // if any 1 exist print 'HARD' else 'EASY', only 1's and 0's
```

```
input()
print('EHAASRYD'['1'in input()::2])
```

Can anybody explain the second line.

Comment: Hint: `True` and `False` are somewhat exchangeable with `1` and `0`. Play around with what `'1' in '0 0 1'` or `'1' in '0 0 0'` results in. Play around with what `'EHAASRYD'[0::2]` and `'EHAASRYD'[1::2]` results in…

Comment: And, in addition to deceze's comment: Unless your aim is to confuse the reader, NEVER program this way.

Comment: This is why code reviews exist

Comment: Relevant documentation: [Built-in Types: Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a pretty confusing way to do this and clearly is not pythonic, but what it does is the following, if input() is '1' then ('1' in input()) is 1 and then the code gets the index 1 of the string and jumps 2 every time, so it will print 'H', 'A', 'R', 'D', if input() is '0' then ('0' in input()) is 0 and then the code gets the index 0 of the string and jumps 2 every time.

A better way to do it is:

```
if ('1' in input()):
    print('HARD')
else:
    print('EASY')
```